# Stored Procedure Optimisation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have written the following SQL Stored Procedure and because of all the select commands (I think) it's really slow running now the database has been populated with lots of data. Is there a way to optimise it so that it runs much quicker? Currently in an Azure S0 DB it takes around 1:40 min to process. Here's the stored procedure:

```
USE [cmb2SQL]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spStockReport] @StockReportId as INT
AS
    select 
        ProductId, 
        QtyCounted, 
        LastStockCount, 
        Purchases, 
        UnitRetailPrice, 
        CostPrice, 
        GrossProfit, 
        Consumed,
        (Consumed * UnitRetailPrice) as ValueOfSales,
        (QtyCounted * CostPrice) as StockOnHand, 
        StockCountId
    from (
        select 
            ProductId, 
            QtyCounted, 
            LastStockCount, 
            Purchases, 
            UnitRetailPrice, 
            CostPrice, 
            GrossProfit, 
            (LastStockCount + Purchases) - QtyCounted as Consumed,
            StockCountId
        from (
            select
                distinct
                sci.StockCountItem_Product as ProductId,  
                (Select ISNULL(SUM(Qty), 0) as tmpQty from 
                    (Select Qty from stockcountitems
                    join stockcounts on stockcountitems.stockcountitem_stockcount = stockcounts.id
                    where stockcountitem_Product = p.Id and stockcountitem_stockcount = sc.id and stockcounts.stockcount_pub = sc.StockCount_Pub
                    ) as data
                ) as QtyCounted,
                (Select ISNULL(SUM(Qty), 0) as LastStockCount from 
                    (Select Qty from StockCountItems as sci
                        join StockCounts on sci.StockCountItem_StockCount = StockCounts.Id
                        join Products on sci.StockCountItem_Product = Products.id
                    where sci.StockCountItem_Product = p.id and sci.stockcountitem_stockcount =
                        (select top 1 stockcounts.id from stockcounts
                        join stockcountitems on stockcounts.id = stockcountitem_stockcount
                        where stockcountitems.stockcountitem_product = p.id and stockcounts.id < sc.id  and StockCounts.StockCount_Pub = sc.StockCount_Pub
                        order by stockcounts.id desc)
                    ) as data
                ) as LastStockCount,
                (Select ISNULL(SUM(Qty * CaseSize), 0) as Purchased from
                    (select Qty, Products.CaseSize from StockPurchaseItems
                        join Products on stockpurchaseitems.stockpurchaseitem_product = products.id
                        join StockPurchases on stockpurchaseitem_stockpurchase = stockpurchases.id
                        join Periods on stockpurchases.stockpurchase_period = periods.id
                    where Products.id = p.Id and StockPurchases.StockPurchase_Period = sc.StockCount_Period and StockPurchases.StockPurchase_Pub = sc.StockCount_Pub) as data
                ) as Purchases,
                sci.RetailPrice as UnitRetailPrice,
                sci.CostPrice,
                (select top 1 GrossProfit from Pub_Products where Pub_Products.Pub_Product_Product = p.id and Pub_Products.Pub_Product_Pub = sc.StockCount_Pub) as GrossProfit,
                sc.Id as StockCountId
            from StockCountItems as sci 
                join StockCounts as sc on sci.StockCountItem_StockCount = sc.Id
                join Pubs on sc.StockCount_Pub = pubs.Id
                join Periods as pd on sc.StockCount_Period = pd.Id
                join Products as p on sci.StockCountItem_Product = p.Id
                join Pub_Products as pp on p.Id = pp.Pub_Product_Product
            Where StockCountItem_StockCount = @StockReportId  and pp.Pub_Product_Pub = sc.StockCount_Pub
            Group By sci.CostPrice, sci.StockCountItem_Product, sci.Qty, sc.Id, p.Id, sc.StockCount_Period, pd.Id, sci.RetailPrice, pp.CountPrice, sc.StockCount_Pub
        ) as data
    ) as final

GO
```

As requested here is the execution plan in XML (had to upload it to tinyupload as it exceeds the message character length):

[execusionplan.xml](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=97403313684323569774)

Schema:

[image: Table Schema]

Row Counts:

```
Table   row_count
StockPurchaseItems  57511
Products    3116
StockCountItems 60949
StockPurchases  6494
StockCounts 240
Periods 30
Pub_Products    5694
Pubs    7
```

Comment: So many subqueries ,SP may not perform well .could you please post actual execution plan in form of XML and also schema of tables involved along with table count

Comment: instead of subquery use join it will gives you good result

Comment: or create temp tables and break down one big query in to many smaller ones then join the results together

Comment: All extra information given as requested.

Comment: I guess I am a layman here, you have a report of stocks such that `StockPurchases` contains A) the period of the individual `StockCounts` obtained from the `StockCountItems` table. B) `StockPurchases` also contains the companies by which you wish to identify the individual company's batch purchases by products (or some combination of them)? You have your Dimension tables (`StockCountItems` and `Products`), so I'm confused as to why you need so many subqueries like yatin said. Perhaps spending more time on were the relation is (from DIM to FACT) might enlighten where "simple" joins are needed?

Comment: `distinct` is totally unnecessary and I suggest to rewrite "double"-subqueries with `ISNULL(SUM(QTY))`: `Sum` should be done with single select, no additional subquery needed and `ISNULL` should be outside of subqiery - in select list of the outer query. E.g. `SELECT ... ProductId, ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) from stockcountitems ...)) QtyCounted`

Comment: Perhaps I was not very clear, you are running multiple scarlar queries for EVERY ROW IN YOUR 2nd subquery. That alone must be terribly expensive. [Avoid Scarlar](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3845381/T-SQL-Best-Practices-150-Don146t-Use-Scalar-Value-Functions-in-Column-List-or-WHERE-Clauses.htm) unless you must.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the query rewrite, it's the most expensive and the last thing you should do probably. Try these steps first, one by one, and measure the impact - time, execution plan, and SET STATISTICS IO ON output. Create the baseline first for these metrics. Stop when you achieve the acceptable performance.

First of all, update statistics on relevant tables, I see some of the estimates are way off. Check the exec plan for estimated vs actual rows - any better now?

Create indexes on StockPurchaseItems(StockPurchaseItem_Product) and on StockCountItems(StockCountItem_Product, StockCountItem_StockCount). Check the execution plan, did optimizer consider using the indexes at all?

Add (include) other referenced columns to those two indexes in order to cover the query. Are they used now?

If nothing of above helped, consider breaking the query into smaller ones. Would be nice to have some real data to experiment with to be more specific.

** That "select distinct" smells real bad, are you sure the joins are all ok?

Comment: He's running at least 15k queries in that section of code...its a mess. #Scarlarftw